# The number of natural number quadruples that satisfy a function.

Tags: number-theory

The question is:

> Find the number of natural number quadruples $(A, B, C, D)$ such that there exists a function $f:\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ that satisfies:
>
> - $f(n^2-2n-1)=A\cdot2^n+B\cdot2^{-n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$
> - $f(n^2-4n+1)=|n-C|+|n-D|$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and
> - $f(2022)=90$

It's easy to see that for $n=1$, then $f(n^2-2n-1)=f(n^2-4n+1)\implies 2A+\frac{B}{2}=|1-C|+|1-D|$.

Also, $n^2-4n+1=2022$ for $n=47$ and $n=-43$, giving me $|47-C|+|47-D|=90$ as well as $|-43-C|+|-43-D|=90$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: In this problem, is $0$ considered to be a natural number?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: @JohnOmielan thank you for having let me play, instead of giving the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The two first requirements may be rewritten

- $\forall a\in\Bbb Z\quad f(a^2-2)=2A\cdot2^a+\frac B2\cdot 2^{-a},$
- $\forall b\in\Bbb Z\quad f(b^2-3)=|b+2-C|+|b+2-D|$

or equivalently

- $B=4A$ and $\forall a\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0}\quad f(a^2-2)=2A\left(2^a+2^{-a}\right),$
- $D=4-C$ and $\forall b\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0}\quad f(b^2-3)=|b+2-C|+|b-2+C|.$

$\forall a,b\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0}\quad a^2-2=b^2-3\Leftrightarrow(b+a)(b-a)=1\Leftrightarrow(a,b)=(0,1)$ hence the two conditions above overlap only at $4A=|3-C|+|C-1|.$

If $0$ is not considered to be a natural number, there is no solution because $1\le D=4-C\Rightarrow C\le3$ and the previous condition becomes $A=\frac12.$

So, let us consider $0$ as a natural number. Then, $(C,D)=(0,4)$ or $(4,0),$ $A=1,$ and $B=4A=4.$

The third requirement is then automatically fulfilled, since $2022=45^2-3$ and  $\forall b\in\Bbb Z_{\ge2}\quad f(b^2-3)=2b.$

Conclusion: the number of solutions in $(\Bbb Z_{\ge0})^4$ is $2.$